# Left join with multiple rows from right table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables (`agents`, `visits`).

Agents can have many visits each with its timestamp

I want to select all agents using `left join` without agent duplicates and if the agent has many visits then show the most recent one i.e select the last timestamp in visits table.

I tried the following query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM agents 
  LEFT 
  JOIN  visits 
    ON agent_id = visit_id 
 GROUP 
    BY agent_id
```

This works well without agent duplicates but shows the oldest visit and I want to show the last one (the most recent timestamp in the second table `visits`).

Comment: you have to use sub query for right table.

Comment: 'This' does not 'work well' under any circumstances!

Comment: @Strawberry please give yourself 10 seconds to understand the question before marking it as a duplicate. It's not even a similar question

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)